# The best overloaded method match for 'Emgu.CV.CvInvoke.cvSnakeImage has some invalid arguments

Tags: c#, image-processing, emgucv

I fixed the last error and that's my new code:

```
    public partial class Form1 : Form
   {
       public Form1()
       {
        InitializeComponent();
         }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
        using (OpenFileDialog dialog = new OpenFileDialog())
        {
            dialog.Filter = "JPEG|*.jpg|PNG|*.PNG";
            if (dialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                pictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;

                Image image = Image.FromFile(dialog.FileName);

                pictureBox1.Image = image;

            }
        }

    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }


    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    struct parameter
    {
        public float alpha { get; set; }
        public float beta { get; set; }
        public float gamma { get; set; }
    };




    unsafe private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        {

        int length = 1000;

        Point *contour;

        Point center = new Point();

        var snake_param = new List<parameter>();

            snake_param.Add(new parameter { alpha=  0.1f , beta = 0.1f, gamma= 0.1f, });

        IntPtr dst_img= new IntPtr();

        Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap("pictureBox1.Image");

        Image<Bgr, byte> image = new Image<Bgr, byte>(bitmap);




        center.X = image.Width;
        center.Y = image.Height;




        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < length; i++)
        {
            contour[i].X = (int)(center.X * Math.Cos(2 * Math.PI * i / length) + center.X);
            contour[i].Y = (int)(center.Y * Math.Sin(2 * Math.PI * i / length) + center.Y);
        }

     LINE_TYPE lignetype = new LINE_TYPE();         


        for (i = 0; i < length - 1; i++)
        {
            CvInvoke.cvLine(
                dst_img,
                contour[i],
                contour[i + 1],
                new MCvScalar(255,0,0),
                2, 
                LINE_TYPE.EIGHT_CONNECTED,
                0  );
        }


        CvInvoke.cvLine
            (
            dst_img,
            contour[length - 1],
            contour[0],
            new MCvScalar(255,0,0),
            2,
            LINE_TYPE.EIGHT_CONNECTED,
            0
            );


           IntPtr ctr =new IntPtr();
           //public void PixelToInkSpace(
            //IntPtr a 
            //ref Point contour
            //);          



        IntPtr src_img = image.Ptr;
        CvInvoke.cvSnakeImage(
            src_img,
            contour[i],
            length, 
            snake_param.[1].alfa,
            snake_param[2].beta,
            snake_param[3].gamma,
            1,
            new System.Drawing.Size(15, 15), 
            new MCvTermCriteria(1,0.0),
            1);



        CvInvoke.cvCvtColor(
            src_img,
            dst_img,
            COLOR_CONVERSION.GRAY2RGB );


            for (i = 0; i < length - 1; i++)
        {
            CvInvoke.cvLine(
                dst_img,
                contour[i],
                contour[i + 1],
                new MCvScalar(255,0,0),
                2, 
                LINE_TYPE.EIGHT_CONNECTED,
                0 );
        }
            CvInvoke.cvLine(
                dst_img, 
                contour[length - 1],
                contour[0], 
                new MCvScalar(255,0,0),
                    2, 
                    LINE_TYPE.EIGHT_CONNECTED,
                    0);
             pictureBox2.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;

             Bitmap bitmappbb = new Bitmap("dst_img");
             Image<Bgr, byte> imagee = new Image<Bgr, byte>(bitmappbb);
             pictureBox2.Image = bitmappbb;
             }


          }
       }
   }
```

But my error now is different as I'm translating my code from c++ to c# ,
I discover that the  snake format is

```
public static void cvSnakeImage(
IntPtr image,
IntPtr points,
int length,
float[] alpha,
float[] beta,
float[] gamma,
int coeffUsage,
Size win,
MCvTermCriteria criteria,
bool calcGradient
```

)

1. I didn't find way to convert the variable "contour" with type "Point" to "IntPtr".
2. And a way to call alfa, beta et gamma as float[]; 
   @Timothy Walters

Comment: Maybe you already posted it elsewhere but taking only this question, it definetly needs more context. What exactly is your problem?

Comment: I didn't find way to convert the variable "contour" with type "Point" to "IntPtr".
And a way to call alfa, beta et gamma as float[]; @nvoigt

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert your srcimg to gray image than using canny method detect the edge and canny output image. You can get the contour.

Here is some example:

```
        //Canny Method 


            cannyEdges = new Image<Gray, byte>(grayImg.Size);
                        CvInvoke.cvCanny(grayImg, cannyEdges, 100, 35, 3);
                        grayImg = cannyEdges;

        //getting contour 

         Contour<Point>[] ResultContour =new Contour<Point>[4];
     int c = 0;
                for (var contours = block.FindContours(CHAIN_APPROX_METHOD.CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE,
                    RETR_TYPE.CV_RETR_EXTERNAL); contours != null; contours = contours.HNext)
                {
    ResultContour[c]=contours ;
    c++
    }
```